# AngularJS like View Rendering on ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, reporting

Hi i'm trying to implement template based dynamic reporting system. i don't know exact term but what i'm trying to do is bind data to html template

```
<div>{{ ReportName }} NoOf Records : {{Count}}</div>
<div> Total Expenses {{ PerDay * TotalDays }} </div>
```

i can came up with replacing fields to relevant properties on my model like this

```
private static string GetContent(string content, Report model)
{
    var types = typeof(AgreementReport); 
    var fields = types.GetProperties(); 
    foreach (var field in fields)
    {
        var tok = field.Name;
        var value = model.GetType().GetProperty(tok).GetValue(model);
        var fulToken = string.Format("{{{0}}}", tok);
        if (content.Contains(fulToken))
            content = content.Replace(fulToken, value != null ? value.ToString() : string.Empty);
    }

    return content;
}
```

but the problem is i need to extend the functionality to support multiplications, addition, divisions just like angularJS does. is there any better approach or how can i achieve this

Thanks

Comment: Is there no way you could embed an angular app into the view and pass the data in via ajax?

Comment: yeah that would be the final approach before that i'm looking for alternative approaches

Comment: if you are doing this in ASP.Net MVC, isn't this what Razor does already?

Comment: let say i'm gonna give the interface to end user for report building and some reports showing  `Total Expenses` as above but some don't so there's no way to templating with Razor isn't?

Comment: @GayanRanasinghe If you just return a `JsonResult` from your MVC controller with the your model. All you need to do is create and angular app in your view/frontend and you will get all the functionality like `{{ }}` templating and the extra support on the client via angular. Does it have to happen server-side?